# Calculate distance in 2D int array efficiently

Tags: c++14, getdistance

I am making a bomberman type game. I want to calculate the distance between two points; players can move in four directions. If I am at (0,0) and want to go to (5,5), I can calculate the distance by using the taxicab distance formula ((5-0) + (5-0)) as I can only move horizontal and vertical.

But now I want to implement walls in the game which the player cannot move through.

My current implementation of distance that just uses taxicab formula.

```
int distanceTo(Position Pos)
{
    return (abs(this->x - Pos.x) + abs(this->y - Pos.y));
}
```

How do I find the distance between two points (x1,y1) and (x2,y2), considering the immovable boxes/walls that come in between?

Comment: Your problem is not very clear

Comment: @eyllanesc please tell which part is not clear so that I edit it accordingly.

Comment: I do not understand what you want.

Comment: @eyllanesc done edit please check if its understandable now.

Comment: If you want to find the path with a minimum number of steps and where there may be obstacles, read about the algorithm A *(aka A star). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm

Comment: Are you moving on a grid? Explain your game more.

Comment: I am moving on a 2D matrix 11 X 13. I represent 1 for empty floor which I can move on and 2 for wall on which player can't be moved I want to distance a distance calculation formula thinking that I am on x1,y1 and want to go to x2, y2 considering that I can't overlap with walls.

Comment: @MatthewHooker please see the comment above

Comment: So you want the best path or multiple paths to that point. Assuming that wall is there, you want to go around it and calculate that distance?

Comment: @MatthewHooker Yes the want the distance of best path assuming I can't overlap with walls.

Comment: Do you understand the Dijkstra algorithm? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

Answer (score 1):

With the obstacles, you'll need to replace your simple taxicab distance formula with a more sophisticated pathfinding algorithm.

How big is your grid? Dijkstra's algorithm would work for small grids, and A* (a modification of Dijkstra's) for larger ones.

Amit Patel has an excellent resource describing Dijkstra's and A*, as well as implementation details for each. You may view it [here](http://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/GameProgramming/).

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. My grid is 11 X 13. Can you please show me an implementation if I use constants 0 for movable place and 1 for immovable. I would really be thankful.